# Method to make definitively static an abandoned WP blog

Tags: cache, static-website

I have a blog, created with WordPress 3.4, which I abandoned some years ago but it is still receiving a good number of visits each day through Google search results.

It means a load for my mySQL server and wondered if there was a method to make the blog definitively static. I don't plan to insert new posts, and I don't allow comments on the old ones.

Any tip is welcome. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install a page caching plugin and configure it for a very very long time. This have the advantage of you being able to post things when you decide that its time to do that again.

Side note: abandoned blog creates actual noticeable load on a DB server? I find it hard to believe. front end wordpress, especially in typical blog setting should not have heavy queries. (this is said as a proud owner of two relatively abandoned blogs)